# Gensim errors after updating Python version with conda

Tags: python-3.x, conda, gensim

I recently updated a conda environment from python=3.4 to python 3.6. The environment is made for a project using [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/) which worked perfectly on 3.4. After this update, using the library generates multiple errors such as:

> TypeError: object of type 'itertools.chain' has no len()

or

> AssertionError: decomposition not initialized yet

Do you guys know why this happens while gensim explicitly says Python 3.5 and 3.6 are supported?

The used code:

```
# Create Texts
texts = src.data.raw.extract_clean_merge_titles_abstracts(papers)
src.data.raw.train_phraser(texts)
texts = src.data.raw.tokenize_stream(texts)

print("Size of corpus: ", len(texts)) # ERROR 1 HERE

# Create Dictionary
dictionary = gensim.corpora.dictionary.Dictionary(texts, prune_at=None)
dictionary.filter_extremes(no_below=3 ,no_above=0.1, keep_n=None)
dictionary.compactify()
print(dictionary)
dictionary.save(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_DICTIONARY)

# Create corpus
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
#gensim.corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_CORPUS, corpus)
corpus_index = gensim.similarities.docsim.Similarity(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_CORPUS_INDEX, corpus, num_features=len(dictionary))
corpus_index.save(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_CORPUS_INDEX)

# tf-idf
tfidf = gensim.models.TfidfModel(corpus)
corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]    #gensim.corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_CORPUS_TFIDF, corpus_tfidf)
tfidf.save(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_TFIDF)
corpus_tfidf_index = gensim.similarities.docsim.Similarity(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_CORPUS_TFIDF_INDEX, corpus_tfidf, num_features=len(dictionary))
corpus_tfidf_index.save(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_CORPUS_TFIDF_INDEX)

# lsa
lsa_num_topics = 100
lsa = gensim.models.LsiModel(corpus_tfidf, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=lsa_num_topics)
corpus_lsa = lsa[corpus_tfidf] # ERROR 2 HERE
#gensim.corpora.MmCorpus.serialize(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_CORPUS_LSA, corpus_lsa)
lsa.save(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_LSA)
corpus_lsa_index = gensim.similarities.docsim.Similarity(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_CORPUS_LSA_INDEX, corpus_lsa, num_features=lsa_num_topics)
corpus_lsa_index.save(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_TEMP_CORPUS_LSA_INDEX)
```

Here is the list of the packages installed:

```
bkcharts                  0.2                      py36_0  
bokeh                     0.12.6                   py36_0  
boto                      2.47.0                   py36_0  
bz2file                   0.98                     py36_0  
cycler                    0.10.0                   py36_0  
dbus                      1.8.20                        1    ostrokach
decorator                 4.0.11                   py36_0  
expat                     2.1.0                         0    ostrokach
fontconfig                2.12.1                        3  
freetype                  2.5.5                         2  
gensim                    2.2.0               np113py36_0  
gettext                   0.19.5                        2    ostrokach
glib                      2.48.2                        0    ostrokach
gst-plugins-base          1.8.0                         0  
gstreamer                 1.8.0                         0  
icu                       54.1                          0    ostrokach
jinja2                    2.9.6                    py36_0  
jpeg                      9b                            0  
libffi                    3.2.1                         8    ostrokach
libgcc                    5.2.0                         0  
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1  
libiconv                  1.14                          0  
libpng                    1.6.27                        0  
libsigcpp                 2.4.1                         3    ostrokach
libxcb                    1.12                          1  
libxml2                   2.9.4                         0  
markupsafe                0.23                     py36_2  
matplotlib                2.0.2               np113py36_0  
mkl                       2017.0.3                      0  
networkx                  1.11                     py36_0  
nltk                      3.2.4                    py36_0  
numpy                     1.13.1                   py36_0  
openssl                   1.0.2l                        0  
pcre                      8.39                          1  
pip                       9.0.1                    py36_1  
pymysql                   0.7.9                    py36_0  
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py36_0  
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py36_2  
python                    3.6.1                         2  
python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py36_0  
pytz                      2017.2                   py36_0  
pyyaml                    3.12                     py36_0  
qt                        5.6.2                         4  
readline                  6.2                           2  
requests                  2.14.2                   py36_0  
scikit-learn              0.18.2              np113py36_0  
scipy                     0.19.1              np113py36_0  
setuptools                27.2.0                   py36_0  
sip                       4.18                     py36_0  
six                       1.10.0                   py36_0  
smart_open                1.5.3                    py36_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
system                    5.8                           2  
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
tornado                   4.5.1                    py36_0  
wheel                     0.29.0                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.2                         1  
yaml                      0.1.6                         0  
zlib                      1.2.8                         3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it came from the Phraser:

```
def tokenize_stream(stream, max_num_words = 3):
    tokens_stream = [gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(t, min_len=2, max_len=50) for t in stream]
    for i,tokens in enumerate(tokens_stream):
        tokens_stream[i] = [j for j in tokens if j not in stop_words]
    phrases = gensim.models.phrases.Phrases.load(config.paths.PATH_DATA_GENSIM_PHRASES)
    grams = gensim.models.phrases.Phraser(phrases)
    tokens_stream = list(grams[tokens_stream]) ## HERE LIST IS IMPORTANT
    return tokens_stream
```

For some reason, with python 3.4, not using "list(grams[...])" did work in my code, and returns an itertool.chain instance which leads to an empty corpus with python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

More context for the errors (including reported stacks) would be necessary to know where the errors are happening.

Gensim is supported and release-tested for Python 3.6, so the issue is likely something specific to your system.

You may want to try uninstalling & reinstalling gensim (or whatever library error stacks also implicates), or starting a fresh conda environment that's Python 3.6 from the beginning.

Comment: What information specifically ? Thx for the suggestion, I try to recreate an environment from scratch and tell you if it worked.

Comment: The errors you list will usually be reported with more information, including the exact lines-of-code where they were triggered (and where those stack frames were called, etc). That would help determine if the problem is in library code or your own code, or some combination.